How to configure AlientVault OSSIM to collect Windows security event logs and send email
I'm completely new to AlienVault OSSIM and I want to start using OSSIM to collect Windows security events from domain controllers e.g. failed login attempts, bad password attempts, account lockouts, user account creation etc.
I have installed the OSSEC agent on my domain controlers, and my questions are:
-do I need to install anythink else like NxLog or Sysmon?
-do I need to configure the OSSEC agent to collect the specific windows events that I need?
-in Alienvault I want send an email in case such event occured on my DC, is it enough to creae a policy or do I need to create plugin or anything else?
